# firestore database listener stops listening / angular / RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

We have created an app that has a listener to a query in Firestore using the following code:

```
   /**
   * Client callback list generation
   */
  private incoming_online_client_for_any_care = (domain: string) => {
    return this.db.collection<db.callingClient>(`domains/${domain}/callingClients`, ref => {
      let query: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
      query = query.where('for', 'array-contains', 'any')
        .where('status', '==', 'is_calling');

      return query;
    }).valueChanges();
  }
```

When we leave the page open for several minutes, the app seems not to respond anymore to changes to this query (actually, when a user on another page opens an app, is_calling will be set or removed).

A refresh of the page immediatedly works.

It is created by calling this function:

`this.clientsForAnyCare$ = this.incoming_online_client_for_any_care(domain);`

Piped: (this.allClients$ is a db call to enrich the clients with name etc)

````
      .pipe(
        map(([a, b]) => {
          return uniqWith(
            sortBy(
              a, ['timestamp']
            )
          ).map(callingClient => {
            if (callingClient) {
             ... enrich code
            }
            return callingClient;
          })
        }),
       );

And used in the template

``` <ng-container *ngIf="nextClient$ | async as bellers;wachten">```
````

Comment: Do you receive more than 1 emission?  I'm wondering if it's stopping after a certain number of emissions or after a certain period of time.  It may be helpful to show the code that uses this method.

Comment: I receive about 3 of 4 emissions. The page can be open a full day!
Is there a timelimit on the db listener or a way to check the connection on interval?

PS i added the whole way from first observable to where it goes in the template.

Comment: PS it is AngularFirestore